# ERROR WHILE RUNNING collect() in PYSPARK

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to separate the website name from the URL. For example - if the URL is www.google.com, the output should be "google". I tried the below code and everything works fine except the last line  - "websites.collect()".

I used a dataframe to store the website names and then converted it to a rdd and applied a split function on the values to get my required output.

The logic seems to be fine but I guess there is some error in my packages configuration and installation.

The error is shown below:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a88287400951> in <module>()
----> 1 websites.collect()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
    822         """
    823         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 824             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    825         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    826 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1158         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1159         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1161 
   1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    321             else:
    322                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

CODE:-

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local[*]")
         .setAppName("Test")
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
       )

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc) 

schemaWebsite = sc.parallelize([
    (0, "www.google.com"), (1, "www.hackerrank.com"),(2, "www.walmart.com/in"),
    (3, "www.amazon.in"),(4, "www.ndtv.com")]).toDF(["id", "ev"])

websites = schemaWebsite.rdd.map(lambda x : x[1].split(".")[1])
websites.collect()
```

Comment: It seems a problem in spark configuration. Can you print the output of sc._conf.getAll()

Comment: [('spark.executor.memory', '16g'),
 ('spark.driver.host', '.........'),
 ('spark.driver.port', '52092'),
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.app.name', 'Test'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
 ('spark.app.id', 'local-1520492861811'),
 ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true')]                                                                   The above is the output.I didn't share "spark.driver.host".....

Comment: what is your spark and java version. Try setting JAVA_HOME to Java 1.8 once.

Answer (score 5):

Just to make @Anubhav Sarangi comment to this question an answer:
I had the same problem. Initially, I installed Java SE 10.0.1. But got similar error. Following @Anubhav Sarangi suggestion, I downloaded and installed [Java SE Development Kit 8u171](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) which has jdk 1.8 and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, but after installing Java SE Development Kit 8u191 and selecting java-8-jdk with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

it dissappered.