# Spark Java IllegalArgumentException at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to use Spark 2.3.1 with Java.

I followed examples [in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-classifier) but keep getting poorly described exception when calling `.fit(trainingData)`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2073)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1358)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1331)
at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.DecisionTreeMetadata$.buildMetadata(DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.run(RandomForest.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(DecisionTreeClassifier.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(DecisionTreeClassifier.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
at com.example.spark.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:36)
```

I took this dummy dataset for classification (`data.csv`):

```
f,label
1,1
1.5,1
0,0
2,2
2.5,2
```

My code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[1]")
            .appName("My App")
            .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .load("C:\\tmp\\data.csv");

    data.show();  // see output(1) below

    VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
            .setInputCols(Collections.singletonList("f").toArray(new String[0]))
            .setOutputCol("features");

    Dataset<Row> trainingData = assembler.transform(data)
            .select("features", "label");

    trainingData.show();  // see output(2) below

    DecisionTreeClassifier clf = new DecisionTreeClassifier();
    DecisionTreeClassificationModel model = clf.fit(trainingData);  // fails here (MyApp.java:36)
    Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(trainingData);

    predictions.show();  // never reached
```

Output(1):

```
+---+-----+
|  f|label|
+---+-----+
|1.0|    1|
|1.5|    1|
|0.0|    0|
|2.0|    2|
|2.5|    2|
+---+-----+
```

Output(2):

```
+--------+-----+
|features|label|
+--------+-----+
|   [1.0]|    1|
|   [1.5]|    1|
|   [0.0]|    0|
|   [2.0]|    2|
|   [2.5]|    2|
+--------+-----+
```

My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = 'MyApp'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.11', version: '2.3.1'
}
```

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What Java version do you have downloaded on your machine?
Your problem is probably related to Java 9.

If you download Java 8 (jdk-8u171, for instance), the Exception will disappear, and output(3) of `predictions.show()` will look like this:

```
+--------+-----+-------------+-------------+----------+
|features|label|rawPrediction|  probability|prediction|
+--------+-----+-------------+-------------+----------+
|   [1.0]|    1|[0.0,2.0,0.0]|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|       1.0|
|   [1.5]|    1|[0.0,2.0,0.0]|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|       1.0|
|   [0.0]|    0|[1.0,0.0,0.0]|[1.0,0.0,0.0]|       0.0|
|   [2.0]|    2|[0.0,0.0,2.0]|[0.0,0.0,1.0]|       2.0|
|   [2.5]|    2|[0.0,0.0,2.0]|[0.0,0.0,1.0]|       2.0|
+--------+-----+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: I am in JD8 and I have the problem

Comment: I had similar issue as I'm using JDK 11 and Scala version is 2.11 , spark version is 2.3.1. Once I have updated Scala version to 2.12 , spark version is 2.4.4, it working fine

Answer (score 3):

I had the same ploblem, my system use Spark 2.2.0 with Java 8, now We would like the upgrade the server, but the Spark 2.3.1 doesn't work with Java 10 yet, in my case I continue working with Java 8 in the Spark Server and upgraded only Spark to 2.3.1

I read same post about the suubject:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24421

[Why apache spark does not work with java 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330840/why-apache-spark-does-not-work-with-java-10)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have java 8 installed and still got this exception you should check to which java version your eclipse is pointing to.
In your eclipse IDE go to

Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs

Now check if its pointing to jre 1.8
If not then click on Add > Standard VM > Next > (provide your jre directory) > Finish